# Multi thread access exception - Karate 1.3.1

Tags: karate

Due to a long execution time, we switched to a multi thread execution of scenarios. There is an exception that is raised that is related to multi thread access.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multi-threaded access requested by thread Thread[http-nio-8778-exec-1,5,main] but is not allowed for language(s) js.

I would to understand how Karate creates new Graal Context. This error seems to arrive on a specific set of scenarios (those that use a Java class that gets Kafka messages using another thread). I suspect that the multi thread exception is raised because this Kafka consumer reads properties that are sent by the scenario (probably a polyglot map). Does it make sense?

I tried to bypass most Javascript used by those scenarios but it seems that what fixed the issue was copying all configuration sent by the scenario (using a map) to a HashMap instead of using the default Polyglot object.

Answer (score 0):

I will point you to this pull request which links to a bunch of other issues that are relevant. Warning: this may be a long read: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/pull/2081

My suggestion is try to move troublesome logic into pure java - and when you call from karate to java - try to avoid JS functions. the moment a JS function that was declared in Karate is invoked - that point is where Graal checks whether any other thread is active. Please make sure you are on Karate 1.4.0 if not already.

Happy to collaborate with you if you are able to create a sample to replicate any obvious issues still present in 1.4.0 - this Graal limitation is extremely unfortunate and IMO un-necessary, and I was thinking of a feature request for Graal to have a config option to switch off that check for JS.

Comment: Please take a look at the following project: https://github.com/eugeniooliveira/karatethreaddemo

This seems to happen when the PolyglotMap is accessed by multiple Java classes on more than one thread.

Comment: @eslio sorry I still have not gotten the time to get to this, I have noted this as an action item here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2329